# Can't use actionlink in a editortemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code

```
@model ContractorScopingDocumentSite.ViewModels.UploadInitialFileVM
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax

@Html.ActionLink(m => m.Name, "Download", "ScopingDocument", new { docID = Model.DocID, fileName = Model.Name }, null);
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-event">Delete <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Size)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Extension)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ToArchive)


<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
<br />
```

I get the error:

> 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
>   'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload
>   'AjaxExtensions.ActionLink(AjaxHelper, string, string, object,
>   AjaxOptions, object)' requires a receiver of type 'AjaxHelper'

I would have though adding the `using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax` line would solve this. Any ideas?

Comment: Not at a development computer at the moment to check myself, but does adding a ; after your using statement fix the issue?

Comment: The first parameter of `ActionLink()` is `string`, not an expression. And remove both those `@using` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Download", "ScopingDocument", new { docID = Model.DocID, fileName = Model.Name }, null);
```

Also check the names of the hidden fields to make sure they're what you expect.